# iOS - Store Video Buffer in Memory to Playback Later

Tags: ios, avcapturesession

I want to have a real-time video buffer of about ten seconds in which I can pull from and play back it's contents at any time. I've tried using:

```
    - (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput
    didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer 
           fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
```

but it doesn't seem to work as I expected. Appreciate any examples or reference since Apple doesn't have much documentation on this method.